# How can I pass through additional metadata with Redux Promise Middleware?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-promise-middleware

With Redux Promise Middleware, we write action like this:

```
export const withdraw=(id)=>{
    return{
        type: WITHDRAW,
        payload: (new PaypalContract()).withdraw(id),
        id
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, redux-promise-middleware won't pass 'id'  in any of the "WITHDRAW_PENDING","WITHDRAW_FULFILLED" OR "WITHDRAW_REJECT". It only passes the promise in payload to action reducer.

In the real environment, we have lots of items to update, each item with an id to identify, so how can I know which item to update? We have to use 'id' to update specified item, but how with Redux Promise Middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux promise middleware follows the ["Flux Standard Action" (FSA)](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action) spec.

You can use the `meta` property to include additional data in the action:

```js
export const withdraw = (id) => {
    return {
        type: WITHDRAW,
        payload: (new PaypalContract()).withdraw(id),
        meta: { id } 
    }
}
```